# How to show SharePoint List content on html based website?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, script, public-website

Is it possible to show SharePoint List data on Static Website without using C# or CSOM?

To Expand further - 
Can use only scripts to do the job and thus trying to ascertain if Websites can read and display the SharePoint Lists data using scripts?

Comment: Static Website? What do you have in mind?

Comment: Updated.... So html based site should be able to read content from spa list using scripts.